# Python list is not preserving order after asyncio operation

Tags: python, python-asyncio, langchain

I'm currently using Python to try and develop an application using LangChain that would be able to scrape a document and put each line into a row of a table/dataframe. Then I would be calling an LLM to cross-reference the value in the row against a vectorstore to check whether there is a relationship or not.

Since there can be hundreds of rows in the resulting dataframe I tried to implement `asyncio` to run the process concurrently ([reference](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/chains/how_to/async_chain)), this is the code I have right now:

```py
@retry(wait=wait_random_exponential(min=1, max=60), stop=stop_after_attempt(6))
async def async_generate(chain, query, line, reply_list):
    if query and not query.isupper() and len(line) <= 6:
        resp = await chain.arun(query=query)
        reply_list.append(resp)
        # debugging
        print("query", query)
        print("response", resp)
        print(reply_list)
    else:
        reply_list.append("")


@retry(wait=wait_random_exponential(min=1, max=60), stop=stop_after_attempt(6))
async def generate_concurrently(line_list, value_list):
    reply_list = []

   ---
   #langchain boilerplate
   ---

    tasks = [async_generate(chain, query, line, reply_list) for query, line in zip(value_list, line_list)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    return reply_list
```

But I'm running into an issue where the response are not maintaing the order of the rows in the dataframe, and the first iteration of the `async_generate` for the `reply_list` return function yields:

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Comply']
```

and the last iteration yields:

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Comply', 'Noted', 'Comply', 'Noted', 'Comply', 'Not applicable for current submission.', 'By Contractor', 'Not applicable for current submission.', 'Noted', 'Noted', 'Noted', 'Not applicable for current submission.', 'Not applicable for current submission']
```

The ideal result for the `reply_list` should look like this:

```
['', '', '', 'Comply', '', 'Not applicable for current submission', 'Comply', 'Not applicable for current submission', '', 'By Contractor', 'By Contractor', '', 'Not applicable for current submission', 'Comply', 'Comply', 'Comply', '', 'Noted', 'By Contractor', 'Noted']
```

It appears that whichever rows that don't meet the conditional are immediately run and appended at the beginning of the list. Is there a remedy to ensure that the async function returns values that correspond to the original row? Or is there a better implementation that I might have overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

The heart of the answer is actually in your question: *"Is there a remedy to ensure that the async function **returns** values that correspond to the original row?"*

The problem is that at present the `async_generate` function doesn't return a result: it writes it to the `reply_list` object which is shared between tasks. So the order of values in that list ends up being whatever order the tasks happen to write to it. It's not too surprising that the `""` entries tend to come first, since those are from the tasks where the `if` condition is False, and so no time is taken up in running a query.

Instead, have the `async_generate` function **return** its result. You can then rely on the behaviour of `asyncio.gather` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather)):

> If all awaitables are completed successfully, the result is an aggregate list of returned values. The order of result values corresponds to the order of awaitables in `aws`.

Schematically your code would then look like:

```
@retry(wait=wait_random_exponential(min=1, max=60), stop=stop_after_attempt(6))
async def async_generate(chain, query, line):  ## no reply_list param now
    if query and not query.isupper() and len(line) <= 6:
        resp = await chain.arun(query=query)
        print("query", query)
        print("response", resp)
        return resp
    else:
        return ""


@retry(wait=wait_random_exponential(min=1, max=60), stop=stop_after_attempt(6))
async def generate_concurrently(line_list, value_list):
    #langchain boilerplate

    tasks = [async_generate(chain, query, line) for query, line in zip(value_list, line_list)]
    reply_list = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    return reply_list
```